# Center a div tag

Tags: html, css

I am displaying a header on every printed page on the HTML, so header only shows in print preview. I used the following for this:

```
<style>
#header {
    display: table-header-group;
}

#main {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

```
<div>
<div id ="header">
    <div class = "print">
        My header
    </div>
</div>

<div id="main">
  Content here....
</div>

 </div>
```

The problem is that as soon as I added table-header-group all of the content or the body in the main div now shows aligned to left handside. It was in the center and it needs to be in the center. But I cant get it to go to the center it just stays in the left hand side. I cant take the table-row-group out because then the header does not get displayed on every page in print preview. is there a way I can still center the content in the middle of the page?

Comment: Why not use a "print"  media query?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#header{
margin : 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: that does nothing, I am trying to arrange the main div to center position.

Comment: use for div tag then instead if header

Answer (score 0):

above header  give width for that div or otherwise give

div align="center"

Comment: that did nothing, trying to arrange the main div to center

Comment: try this <div align="center"> above "header" div

Answer (score 0):

```
#header{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto 
}
```

This centers the whole thing. Obviously, change the ID to whatever it is.

hash(#) is used for id
dot(). for class and
here header is used like html5 tag

```
header{
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto 
    }
```